# Overlapping Issue - SSRS Report Export to PDF

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

When I export SSRS Report to PDF, Data gets overlapped.

See below image,

[image]

*Can anyone please help me!* *Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure, that the property of textbox - **CanGrow** to True - Instead of **False**.

Comment: Thanks Gooooku! I made a simple mistake! Thanks again. :)